# Xcode 10 iOS simulator slowing down entire system

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode10

Since the upgrade to Xcode 10 on my iMac, all newer iOS simulators (iPhone X and up) are running terribly slow, and the same is on with any other app running including Xcode.

I literally can't type a single character in Xcode due to the slow response time (one keyboard keypress takes 1-6 seconds until the character appears in the editor).

There doesn't even seen to be such a huge load on the machine:

[image]

Here's my system specification:

- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011)
- 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5
- 12 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- AMD Radeon HD 6770M 512 MB

Has anyone else faced the similar issues? Any ideas how to have at least a normal usable workflow?

Comment: I am not sure this question belong here. But here are some thoughts. 1. It's seems unlikely to have slow system due to simulator. 2. Launch activity monitor and see which process are eating up clock time. Also check for memory. 3. Update your OS to mojave (I run with xcode 10 on mojave and all works perfectly fine).

Comment: mojave is not availibile for the imac and the activity monitor doesn't show a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere, that you need a graphic card with metal support to work simulator of xcode 10 properly. I have the same issue on mac pro 5.1 with radeon 5770, which does not support metal. But on macbook pro 2013 it works fine.

Comment: could you provide the reference?